# How to loop past metadata at the beginning of a data file?

Tags: numpy

I have got a data file, with data at the top and then 2 columns of data. What I am trying to do is loop past the data and then split the 2 columns into separate arrays, so I can plot them.

Comment: Can you provide an example file?

Comment: First make sure you understand what the `enumerate` is producing.  It isn't just a string.  If necessary do `print(line)`.  What's `metadata`?  If you want the `genfromtxt` to start when the `file` loop stopped, you need to include it in the `open` context.

Comment: @hpaulj Just edited the question, made a mistake about `metadata`, shouldn't have been in the code. I'll have to look into what `enumerate` actually does, I am not great at coding and I don't really understand what it does haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intention seems to be to loop through the file until you hit `"END_OF_METADATA"`. That's the right idea. But you close the file after you've reached that line and then let `np.genfromtext` open it again.

Try:

```
with open("filedata.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() == "END_OF_METADATA":
            break
    data = np.genfromtxt(file, skip_header=1)
```

Output (`print(data)`):

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.52491663e-03],
       [1.59154943e+03, 3.54231419e-03],
       [3.18309886e+03, 3.55984087e-03],
       [4.77464829e+03, 3.57749795e-03],
       [6.36619772e+03, 3.59528672e-03],
       [7.95774715e+03, 3.61320850e-03],
       [9.54929658e+03, 3.63126461e-03],
       [1.11408460e+04, 3.64945640e-03],
       [1.27323954e+04, 3.66778524e-03],
       [1.43239449e+04, 3.68625250e-03],
       [1.59154943e+04, 3.70485958e-03],
       [1.75070437e+04, 3.72360790e-03],
       [1.90985932e+04, 3.74249889e-03],
       [2.06901426e+04, 3.76153400e-03],
       [2.22816920e+04, 3.78071470e-03]])
```

Comment: This has worked for me, but for some reason the dimensions of the array are different? Instead of 2 columns it gives me 2 rows. The data is all correct by the way it is in the array is weird?

Thanks for the response though it has solved some of the issue for me :)

Comment: @idislikecoding Did you try without the `unpack=True`?

Comment: @idislikecoding Hm, I can't replicate that from the data you've included in your question?